# bug in the crack?

Tags: ruby, json, yaml

I am working with Rubyoverflow gem which allow to work with Stackoverflow API from Ruby code. And I noticed that sometimes I get error message:

```
Invalid JSON string
```

I have tried to analyze code and find out that the error occured when the Stackoverflow's answer has non ascii characters.

Rubyoverflow uses HTTParty gem, and HTTParty gem uses Crack gem to parse JSON files.

```
module Crack
  class JSON
    def self.parse(json)
      json =  json.delete!("^\u{0000}-\u{007F}")  # here is my fix
      YAML.load(unescape(convert_json_to_yaml(json)))
    rescue ArgumentError => e
      raise ParseError, "Invalid JSON string"
    end
```

I have added one line of code to remove all non ascii characers from JSON and the error was fixed.

Now I want to understand who is the person I need to report about this error.

1. Is it possible to include non ascii characters to JSON document?
2. Is it possible to include non ascii characters to YAML document?
3. If standarts allow to include non-ascii characters to JSON and YAML -> error in YAML class. Is it right? Who is the author of this class and which is the best way to fix this bug?

Comment: A quick search shows [the author can be reached at github](https://github.com/eadz/rubyoverflow). That is where you'd file a bug report if it truly is a bug. I don't think it is, but instead I think the problem is you don't understand the spec, or how to deal with Unicode. I'd like to see the question revised, because "I want to understand who is the person I need to report about this error" is not really a good question for SO at this point.

Comment: There is not my code in this example. Stackoverflow publish the JSON, Rubyoverflow works with this JSON, HTTParty gets this JSON, Crack converts JSON to YAML and YAML-lib load this YAML. The question is who of them the reson of error. Why did you decide that the reason in Rubyoverflow? Are you sure the Stackoverflow give the correct JSON? Are you sure that all other gems and libraries works correctly?

Comment: @the Tin Man: Make sure you link to the right github project ;).  That's a fork of the original project, with no additional commits

Comment: @phsr, well, since you didn't link to the right one... [phsr's Rubyoverflow](https://github.com/phsr/rubyoverflow) :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JSON and YAML documents should be decoded according to the charset given in the HTTP headers, and then the resulting document should be parsed appropriately. Both JSON and YAML *do* have a way of expressing non-ASCII characters in ASCII, but neither mandates their use as opposed to using a full encoding.